# Get the combobox from data template in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

I have a WPF Datagrid, with a datatemplate column for combobox

```
<DataGrid Name="grdTest"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TestsList,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="120">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header >
            <TextBlock Text="Test Name" ToolTip="Test Name" Width="109"/>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox  Name="cbxTest" 
        SelectedValue="{Binding TestID,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        DisplayMemberPath="Test" SelectedValuePath="TestID" SelectionChanged="cbxTest_SelectionChanged_1"
        ItemsSource ="{Binding Path=TestList}">
                </ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I'm trying to get the combobox element in the CellEditEnding event of the datagrid as below:

```
 FrameworkElement elmtTest = grdTest.Columns[7].GetCellContent(e.Row);
 ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(elmtTest);
 DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
 ComboBox myComboBox = (ComboBox)myDataTemplate.FindName("cbxTest", myContentPresenter);
```

elmtTest  is of type System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.
But the content template gives null. How can I get the combobox element of the datagrid column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work. It was a dumb mistake from my end. I had to pass combobox to FindVisualChild.

```
FrameworkElement elmtTest = grdTest.Columns[7].GetCellContent(e.Row);
ComboBox myComboBox = FindVisualChild<ComboBox>(elmtTest);
```

Comment: i am trying the same, but I am getting "FindVisualChild" does not exist in the current context." What should I do?